# React setState, using array methods in callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently following a [React course on Scrimba](https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/notes-app-bump-recent-note-to-the-top-co3094396ae8a6fba32c9d71c) on creating a web app for taking notes.

The problem requires me to bump a note to the top of the note list every time it's updated.

The notes are initialised through useState as follows:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([])
```

The array consists of the individual notes as objects with an `id` and `body`

Every time an `onChange` is triggered, the following function is ran:

```
function updateNote(text) {
        setNotes(oldNotes => {
            let updated = oldNotes.map(oldNote => {
            return oldNote.id === currentNoteId
                ? { ...oldNote, body: text }
                : oldNote
            })
            const currNoteIndex = updated.findIndex(
                note => note.id === currentNoteId
                )
            console.log(currNoteIndex)
            updated.unshift(updated.splice(currNoteIndex, 1))
            return updated
        })
    }
```

However, I keep getting an error as shown in the image.

[image: Error Message]

It's very unclear to me where the problem lies, but I'm thinking it has to do with the array methods.

Any explanation for this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please provide the full error you get the image is not helping here

Comment: It says the error is in the Sidebar component. Is that the code from the Sidebar component?

Comment: Also could you open your browser console and show the complete error  please?

Comment: This is what I think is happening: `updated.splice(currNoteIndex, 1)` --> this will change `updated` and will return an **`"ARRAY"`** as the result. It will not return the one item that you spliced from the array - it will return an array. So, after you get that array, you are doing `updated.unshift(**THAT_ARRAY**)`. Effectively, changing 0-th element of `updated` to an array instead of an element. Obviously, I'm very new to javascript - so I may be 100% wrong. Apologies, if that's the case.

Comment: Here's what I tried: `const ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; ar1.unshift(...ar1.splice(1, 1)); console.log(ar1);` versus `const ar1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; ar1.unshift(ar1.splice(1, 1)); console.log(ar1);` (this second variant one makes first element to become an array).

Comment: @jsN00b Ah I completely missed the fact that array.unsplice returns an array, not the object! That solved the problem completely, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [jsN00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658816/jsn00b) for the answer:

array.splice returns an array, not the object.

Since that array is inserted to the start of the array containing the objects, there will be an error when `updateNote()` is called again.